# Blocking of infrared radiation from the sun by $\rm CO_2$

Tags: earth, atmospheric-science, infrared-radiation, climate-science

Why is the infrared heat from the sun not prevented from entering the earth's atmosphere by $\rm CO_2$ to the same extent that it is prevented from leaving the Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: The second answer provided in the question link above provides a perfect explanation to the OPs question. Be sure to check it out.

Comment: Those words, "infrared heat," are leading you astray. About half of the heat delivered to the Earth by sunlight is delivered as _visible_ light. Also, another big chunk of heat is delivered by shorter IR wavelengths that are not absorbed by atmospheric gasses.

Answer (score 4):

The radiation from sun is shorter wavelength than the radiation from earth. $\rm CO_2$ absorbs radiation mostly at wavelengths that the earth radiates. See this [illustration of a publication](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-Black-body-emission-curves-of-the-Sun-and-the-Earth-b-absorption-spectra-of-the_fig10_282393775).

Answer (score 0):

Scattering is important here. Absorption does not mean that atoms or molecules absorb some specific wavelength and attenuate it. Any atom re-emits it. But while the re-emitting, emitting direction is random.

[image]

So atmosphere acts as a big scatterer and atoms and molecules that absorb infrared like $CO_2$ scatter more and infinite absorbing and re-emitting traps the energy